# Override global css with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following situation:

```
.my-nice-class {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
```

This code lies in the first `<style>...</style>` in the html page.
I would like to override this global css, by setting for instance new properties values like in the example below:

```
.my-nice-class {
  max-width: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
}
```

How can I accomplish this with pure Javascript?

Thank you all,

Nano

Comment: Try something like <script>document.getElementsByClassName("my-nice-class").style.max-width = "40%";</script>  Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: Without javascript you can use below the code:-

.my-nice-class {
  max-width: 40% !important;
  max-height: 40% !important;
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify the css as you want by modifying this object

```
document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML
```

**OR**

Modify style attribute of relevant DOM objects

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-nice-class").style[0] = "max-width: 40%;max-height: 40%;"
```

***NOTE:*** You have to use a for loop instead of `style[0]` if you have multiple objects.

Answer (score 2):

For a scalable solution to this problem you could also consider to go for a BEM implementation where you will add and remove modification classes.

```
//HTML
<div class='my-nice-class my-nice-class--dimensions_A'></div>
```

Then the css:

```
CSS:
.my-nice-class--dimensions_A {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

.my-nice-class--dimensions_B {
   max-width: 40%;
   max-height: 40%;
}
```

Then the javascript can add and remove this classes

```
//Javascript
var htmlEl = document.getElementsByClassName('my-nice-class')[0]; // in case you need the first element from the elements array
htmlEl.classList.add("my-nice-class--dimensions_B");
htmlEl.classList.remove("my-nice-class--dimensions_A"); // cleaner but optional, since cascading character of css will render --B first anyway at this point
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("nav-questions").style.maxHeight="40%";
document.getElementsByClassName("nav-questions").style.maxWidth="40%";
```

This line of code automatically override the global css as priority of JS applied css are always higher(even then inline css).

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns HTMLCollection and you cannot just assign style to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda old, but none of those worked for me. Maybe the difference lies in EcmaScript standards, maybe in that I'm having multiple elements of provided CSS class.

Accessing the `style` variable under any of `document.getElementsByClassName("class-one")` or `document.querySelectorAll('.class-one', '.class-two')` results in `undefined`. To have a consistent function, there always should be an assumption of having multiple elements returned in `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`, so the looping is necessary.

Aligning the proper answer to ES6 (maybe ES5) standards would be to loop through results of the function:

In case of the `getElementsByClassName`:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class-one");
for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   elements.item(i).style = "....";
}
```

In case of the `querySelectorAll`, the `forEach` can be used:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class-one');
elements.forEach(element => {
    element.style.color = "white";
    element.style.height = "80%";
    //accessing the single properties of style one by one is the preferred way 
    //than changing the whole `style` string 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-nice-class").style.maxWidth= "40%";
document.getElementsByClassName("my-nice-class").style.maxHeight= "40%";
```

Comment: no, `-` is not valid javascript, use `maxHeight` and `maxWidth`

Comment: I was verifying it rn!
It seemed weird to me after I posted it..
Thanks @TryingToImprove !

Comment: Can you really set the property on the NodeList without iterating?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("footer01__pusher");
cls[0].style.height='132px';
cls[0].style.color='#ff0000';
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="footer01__pusher" style="height: 165px;">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

```
style: CSSStyleDeclaration
0: "display"
1: "height"
additiveSymbols: ""
alignContent: ""
alignItems: ""
alignSelf: ""
alignmentBaseline: ""
all: ""
animation: ""
animationDelay: ""
animationDirection: ""
animationDuration: ""
animationFillMode: ""
animationIterationCount: ""
animationName: ""
animationPlayState: ""
animationTimingFunction: ""
appearance: ""
ascentOverride: ""
aspectRatio: ""
backdropFilter: ""
background: ""
backgroundAttachment: ""
backgroundBlendMode: ""
backgroundClip: ""
backgroundColor: ""
backgroundImage: ""
backgroundOrigin: ""
backgroundPosition: ""
backgroundPositionX: ""
backgroundPositionY: ""
backgroundRepeat: ""
backgroundRepeatX: ""
backgroundRepeatY: ""
backgroundSize: ""
baselineShift: ""
blockSize: ""
border: ""
borderBlock: ""
borderBlockColor: ""
borderBlockEnd: ""
borderBlockEndColor: ""
borderBlockEndStyle: ""
borderBlockEndWidth: ""
borderBlockStart: ""
borderBlockStartColor: ""
borderBlockStartStyle: ""
borderBlockStartWidth: ""
borderBlockStyle: ""
borderBlockWidth: ""
borderBottom: ""
borderBottomColor: ""
borderBottomLeftRadius: ""
borderBottomRightRadius: ""
borderBottomStyle: ""
borderBottomWidth: ""
borderCollapse: ""
borderColor: ""
borderEndEndRadius: ""
borderEndStartRadius: ""
borderImage: ""
borderImageOutset: ""
borderImageRepeat: ""
borderImageSlice: ""
borderImageSource: ""
borderImageWidth: ""
borderInline: ""
borderInlineColor: ""
borderInlineEnd: ""
borderInlineEndColor: ""
borderInlineEndStyle: ""
borderInlineEndWidth: ""
borderInlineStart: ""
borderInlineStartColor: ""
borderInlineStartStyle: ""
borderInlineStartWidth: ""
borderInlineStyle: ""
borderInlineWidth: ""
borderLeft: ""
borderLeftColor: ""
borderLeftStyle: ""
borderLeftWidth: ""
borderRadius: ""
borderRight: ""
borderRightColor: ""
borderRightStyle: ""
borderRightWidth: ""
borderSpacing: ""
borderStartEndRadius: ""
borderStartStartRadius: ""
borderStyle: ""
borderTop: ""
borderTopColor: ""
borderTopLeftRadius: ""
borderTopRightRadius: ""
borderTopStyle: ""
borderTopWidth: ""
borderWidth: ""
bottom: ""
boxShadow: ""
boxSizing: ""
breakAfter: ""
breakBefore: ""
breakInside: ""
bufferedRendering: ""
captionSide: ""
caretColor: ""
clear: ""
clip: ""
clipPath: ""
clipRule: ""
color: ""
colorInterpolation: ""
colorInterpolationFilters: ""
colorRendering: ""
columnCount: ""
columnFill: ""
columnGap: ""
columnRule: ""
columnRuleColor: ""
columnRuleStyle: ""
columnRuleWidth: ""
columnSpan: ""
columnWidth: ""
columns: ""
contain: ""
containIntrinsicSize: ""
content: ""
contentVisibility: ""
counterIncrement: ""
counterReset: ""
counterSet: ""
cssFloat: ""
cssText: "display: block; height: 2000px;"
cursor: ""
cx: ""
d: ""
descentOverride: ""
direction: ""
display: "block"
dominantBaseline: ""
emptyCells: ""
fallback: ""
fill: ""
fillOpacity: ""
fillRule: ""
filter: ""
flex: ""
flexBasis: ""
flexDirection: ""
flexFlow: ""
flexGrow: ""
flexShrink: ""
flexWrap: ""
float: ""
floodOpacity: ""
font: ""
fontDisplay: ""
fontFamily: ""
fontFeatureSettings: ""
fontKerning: ""
fontOpticalSizing: ""
fontSize: ""
fontStretch: ""
fontStyle: ""
fontVariant: ""
fontVariantCaps: ""
fontVariantEastAsian: ""
fontVariantLigatures: ""
fontVariantNumeric: ""
fontVariationSettings: ""
fontWeight: ""
gap: ""
grid: ""
gridArea: ""
gridAutoColumns: ""
gridAutoFlow: ""
gridAutoRows: ""
gridColumn: ""
gridColumnEnd: ""
gridColumnGap: ""
gridColumnStart: ""
gridGap: ""
gridRow: ""
gridRowEnd: ""
gridRowGap: ""
gridRowStart: ""
gridTemplate: ""
gridTemplateAreas: ""
gridTemplateColumns: ""
gridTemplateRows: ""
height: "2000px"
hyphens: ""
imageOrientation: ""
imageRendering: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

To change style `margin` for your `.my-nice-class` global rule:

```
<style id=theStyleElement>
.my-nice-class {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
</style>
```

`theStyleElement.sheet.rules[0].style.maxWidth= "40%";`

sadly I couldn't find how to set "!important" there in `CSSStyleDeclaration` without changing whole `cssText`